# EventEmitter is deprecated and shouldn't be used

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

In AngularDart 3.0.0 EventEmitter is deprecated. So, how to send event from child component to parent?

Before update it is looks like:

```
@Component(
  selector: 'my-test',
  templateUrl: 'test.component.html'
)
class TestComponent {
  @Input()
  String name = '';

  @Output()
  EventEmitter<String> onNameChange = new EventEmitter<String>();
}

...    
onNameChange.emit('New Name');
...
```

Now I need use Stream and StreamController. Can someone give an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a normal `StreamController`

```
final _onNameChangeController = new StreamController<String>.broadcast();
@Output()
Stream<String> get onNameChange => _onNameChangeController.stream;
```

`.broadcast` is optional. It is required to allow multiple subscribers.

See also https://www.dartlang.org/articles/libraries/broadcast-streams

Comment: The 3.0.0 docs are out. Use of StreamController/Stream instead of EventEmitter is also illustrated in the docs under https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/template-syntax#custom-events